# Change HTML attribute in neovim

Tags: vim, neovim

I found myself struggling with quickly changing attributes inside HTML tags.

For example, I have the following code

```
<div className="expense-date">
  <div className="expense-date__@@@year">{year}</div>
  <div>{month}</div>
  <div>{day}</div>
</div>
```

My cursor is where the `@@@` is, and I want to delete the whole attribute: `className="expense-date__@@@year"`.

Is there any text object I can use to quickly delete it? Currently I use `T ct>` (or `T ct`  if there's another attribute), but that's obviously not good enough and won't work if there's a space inside the attribute's value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no built-in "attribute" text object but you can *approximate* one with something generic like this:

```
va"oB
```

where:

- `va"` selects the value,
- `o` moves the cursor to the other side of the selection,
- `B` extends the selection to the beginning of the attribute.

This can be turned into *quick and dirty* pseudo-text objects:

```
xnoremap ix a"oB
onoremap ix :<C-u>normal vix<CR>
xnoremap ax a"oBh
onoremap ax :<C-u>normal vax<CR>
```

- a visual mode mapping that covers the desired text,
- an operator-pending mode mapping that uses the visual mode one,

to use like this:

```
yix
dax
vix
cax
…
```

See [this plugin](https://github.com/whatyouhide/vim-textobj-xmlattr) for a much smarter implementation.

---

Note that nothing in this answer is guaranteed to work in Neovim.

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, there is no simple way to do this; unless you perform a deep syntax analysis, there will always be some caveats.

You can however improve your technique, for example with `F"F=bF d2f"`.

- `F"` goes to the beginning of the string;
- `F=` goes to the previous `=` sign, skipping eventual spaces between;
- `b` goes to attribute name (eventualy in the middle of it e.g. for `data-my-attr`), skipping eventual spaces;
- `F`  goes to the 1st space before the attribute name;
- `d2f"` (or `c2f"`) performs the job.

Of course, you can use it as a macro with `q` and `@` in order to simplify its use.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another option:

```
vi>   ........ visual select inner <>
o ............ jump to the other side
w ............ jump to the next word
```